# Adding a final review page to entityform, before submit

Tags: 7, entities

I have a complex entityform, where I'd like the user to see what has been entered on a final "review" page, before the data is written away.

As far as I can see the preview page, on entityforms, is shown AFTER the data is saved.

Can this be achieved?

So to be clear..

Step 1 : User enters data into form, and clicks "Review"

Step 2 : User sees all the data nicely presented, and clicks "Confirm", or "Edit"

Step 3: If Confirmed, data is written away, otherwise go to Step 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rob, I created Entityforms.

> As far as I can see the preview page, on entityforms, is shown AFTER
>   the data is saved.

Actually when the "preview" page is shown the submission hasn't been saved yet.